# How to force Windows 7 to disable driver signature enforcement?

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers, wifi-driver

I want to boot windows 7 every time with "disable driver signature enforcement". Because every time I didn't do so, my WLAN adapter "Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377" didn't work.

I tried `bcdedit.exe` hacks but it didn't work, the only way to get my wifi working is to press <kbd>F8</kbd> and choose "disable driver signature enforcement"

So, is there any hack or workaround to make it the default without pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>?

Comment: What bcdedit commands did you try?

Comment: bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON

Comment: See this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/).

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question. But, maybe the better question to ask is why is this driver having this issue? Rather than disable an important part of the OS to protect it, you should be trying to get a properly working driver.

Comment: @Appleoddity> ` But, maybe the better question to ask is why is this driver having this issue?` As is usually the case with things like this, the manufacturer stopped supporting the product and doesn't provide newer drivers that are compatible, and not everybody can throw out their old stuff and just buy all new things every few years.

Comment: @Synetech Except the Qualcomm QCA9377 is a modern, fully supported WiFi module with both Windows 7 and Windows 10 drivers available.

Comment: That doesn't mean that the device manufacturer provides current drivers for that device that contains the chipset. With some luck, a generic driver might work (at least the basic functionality, if not all the custom extensions), but that isn't always the case. Moreover, this question applies just as equally to cases where the device isn't supported (in my case, I found this page trying to get an old and discontinued—but good—USB gamepad to work whose drivers aren't signed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do that:

1. **Import certificates prior to install**

> Follow these steps:
>
> 1. install the software once manually by confirming that the unsigned drivers shall be used
> 2. go to %windir%\inf and search for the latest OEM??.INF file; open it (notepad) and verify by its contents that this is the driver you
>      wish to install automatically next time
> 3. go to %windir%\system32\catroot{any ID}\OEM??.CAT (<- same number as in step 2); right click on this file, select properties, go to
>      "Digital Signatures" tab, mark the certificate, click on details
> 4. on the next window click "Show Certificate"
> 5. on the next window open the "Details" tab and click "Save to File..."
> 6. collect this/all certificates
> 7. deploy these certificates
>      7.1 either in a batch /cmd script using "certutil.exe -f -addstore "TrustedPublisher" "MYFILE.cer" prior to setup
>      7.2 or by Group Policies (computer \ Policies \ Windows \ Security \ Public Key Policies \ add your files here )
> 8. run your setup just the way you wanted

2. **Using  Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider**

   - Download the application from the [Softpedia link](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Video-Tweak/Driver-Signature-Enforcement-Overrider.shtml).
   - Right click on it and choose "Run as administrator". Inside its main menu, press on the “Enable Test Mode” button and follow the instructions on the screen. This will enable TESTSIGNING mode, which allows unverified system files to be loaded.
   - Now all you have to do is to add the unverified signature to the required system files. To do so press on the “Sign a System File” button from the main menu, and enter specific filename including full path. For example: if ATITool64.sys from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` refuses to load due to driver signature enforcement, you should type: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\ATITool64.sys`, and if you would like to sign more than a single file, just repeat this procedure until you’re done, and finally reboot.
   - After you enabled Test Mode and added signatures to the required system files, they should bypass Windows’s driver signature enforcement and load without any issues. However, if for some reason you are interested to revert it, you can re-launch the application, choose “Disable Test Mode” from the main menu, and reboot.

Note: DSEO requires administrative privileges (Run as administrator).

**Acknowledgements**

1. [Permanently disable driver signature enforcement on Win 7 x64](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9b6eee60-855d-47cc-9927-acae3fb6f971/permanently-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-on-win-7-x64?forum=w7itprohardware)